# I need to insert the values from the second table to the first table whenewer the ID matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables . Below is the fields description.
 1st table Fields: EmployeeID, Name, EmployeeStatus, PreferredName

2nd table Fields:  EmployeeID, PreferredName

I need to insert the values of PreferredName from 2nd table to the first table whenever EmployeeID matches. Currently all values of PreferredName in the 1st table are null. If no match by EmployeeID they should remain null . This is SQL Server.

I am trying something like :

```
insert into  [Table1] PreferredName  values 

SELECT  
      [PreferredName]

  FROM [Table2]
  where [EmployeeID] in (SELECT  EmployeeID FROM [Table1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want to `UPDATE` the table, not `INSERT` new data. For that, you can use an `UPDATE` with `JOIN` query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.PreferredName = table2.PreferredName
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.EmployeeID = table1.EmployeeID
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6c8bba69c25bd5db0a9b14260481075)

Comment: Accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use `not exists` keyword

```
insert into table1 (preferredname) 
select t2.preferredname
from table2 t1 where
    not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.preferredname = t2.preferredname)
```